# SystemC: SC_THREAD does not start

Tags: systemc

My simple "HelloWorld" program does not work. The programs prints the usual SystemC copyright notice, but not the "Hello World" string).

If I write a similar program using `SC_METHOD` (removing `wait` calls), I can see the printed message.

What causes this?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "systemc.h"

    SC_MODULE(stim)
    {
        sc_in<bool> Clk;

        void StimGen()
        {
            cout << "Hello World!\n";
            wait();
            cout << "Hello again, world!\n";
            wait();
        }
        SC_CTOR(stim)
        {
            SC_THREAD(StimGen);
            sensitive << Clk.pos();
        }
    };


    int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        sc_clock TestClk("clk", 10,SC_NS);

        stim Stim1("Stimulus");
        Stim1.Clk(TestClk);

        sc_start();  // run forever

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answe, but it looks like I solved the issue. 
There was an installation problem.

Re-installing using option  --enable-pthreads while configuring the installation solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During installation of SystemC libraries, compile it with `--enable-pthreads` option. This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me using SystemC 2.3.1 (from Accellera) and Clang 6.0 on OS X: I see both hello prints coming from the thread process.

```
$ ./main
        SystemC 2.3.1-Accellera --- Nov 29 2014 15:29:06
        Copyright (c) 1996-2014 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
Hello World!
Hello again, world!
```

I'm not sure why you are seeing different behavior. Could it be some sort of IO buffering behavior in your host OS? You could try changing the `sc_start()` line to `sc_start(20, SC_NS)` to run for a bounded amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, too.
Maybe try to flush the output buffer of stdout?
Use endl instead of '\n' or `cout << flush`